# Why I don't need to use array_push in associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I was using this code, but If I used `array_push()` it was inserting values with `null`, I was using `array_push` to enter values in the array

```
foreach ($_POST['record_num'] as $check_rec_num) {
    if(!in_array($check_rec_num, $_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno])) {
        array_push($_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno][], $check_rec_num);
    }
}
```

but when I used this it was automatically adding values in the array, without using `array_push` why is that so?

```
foreach ($_POST['rec_num'] as $check_rec_num) {
    if(!in_array($check_rec_num, $_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno])) {
        $_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno][] = $check_rec_num;
    }
}
```

1st example

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 35 ) [2] => )
```

2nd example (without bar brackets)

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 35 [2] => 34 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

Array Design 3rd example without using `array_push` how the hell it is adding the values automatically at the end of the array without `array_push`?

```
Array ( 
   [1] => Array ( 
          [0] => 36 
          [1] => 35 
      ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
          [0] => 33 
          [1] => 32
      )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `[]` in

```
array_push($_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno][], $check_rec_num);
```

This will do it:

```
$_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno], $check_rec_num);
```

See the manual on [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

> Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.

Yet, you should better use `$_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno][]` since

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Comment: nah, that returns me an index with empty value

Comment: @CreepyFrog This is because you have not defined `$_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno]` as an array.

Comment: Do I need to push array inside the array first?

Comment: If you do `[]`, you don't have to define it as an array (or push anything) since it automatically creates one for you. `array_push` is better if you want to push a lot of values at the same time. It seems like you are adding to the array one by one, and using `[]` is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the extra `[]`
Remove it and it'll work:

```
array_push($_SESSION['selected_record'][$pageno], $check_rec_num);
```